# custom tableview cells with different background images for ios application

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to design a tableview such that each cell has a different background image depending on a condition. There are 10 images for cell background and I want to load them as such that the image pattern is repeated on the cells. For example, cells 1-10 take images from 1-10 respectively. Then cells 11-20 also take images 1-10 and so on. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give image name like: images_1/2.../10.png

```
 //write it

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";

  CustomCell  *Cell  = (CustomCell *)[tabeleYourTurn dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (Cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObject= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        }

        for (id currentobject in topLevelObject)
        {
            if ([currentobject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                Cell = (CustomCell *) currentobject;

                break;
            }
        }
    }

 NSString *image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"images_%d.png", indexPath.row % 10 + 1];
 Cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:image];

return Cell;

}
```

May be it will work.

Answer (score 3):

First create an array with ImageName..

Like

```
NSArray *ImageArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1.png",@"2.png"];
```

Then this array with 10 images

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}


// create a background image for the cell:
    UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [cell setBackgroundView:bgView];
    [cell setIndentationWidth:0.0];


((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:[ImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row%10]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your image names are 1, 2...10, you can try to do something like this:

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row % 10 + 1];
```

Than you can use this imageName where you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if( (indexPath.row % 10 ) <= 1)
    {
        // set your image
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is no need to write if condition 10 times if the file names are proper...